# Emacs opens "Messages" pane on startup

Tags: emacs

On startup Emacs now opens a pane labelled "*Messages*" in addition to the "*scratch*" pane.  How can I modify my configuration to suppress this?

Google seaches just seem to give me ways to suppress the splash screen.

I have just modified by `init.el`, but I searched through the changes, and didn't see anything related to the keyword 'message'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the problem happen when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`, that is, with **no init file**?

- If so, `M-x report-emacs-bug`.
- If not, **recursively bisect your init file** to find out which part of it is leading to this behavior.

  You can do that using `comment-region` to comment out first 1/2 of your init file, then 3/4, then 7/8, etc.  With `C-u`, command `comment-region` *uncomments* the region.

Comment: Seems to be due to a `(with-temp-buffer (shell-command...` that was added to my init.

Comment: So did you get your answer and solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can add these lines to your `.emacs` configuration file ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23365580/1081936)):

```
;; Forces the messages to 0, and kills the *Messages* buffer 
(setq-default message-log-max nil)
(kill-buffer "*Messages*")
```

The trick is to set the number of messages to 0 which stops the buffer from appearing. Note that you might want to change this back at some point if your emacs is having problems.

Comment: That works around the problem. It is usually better to find out what the problem is, and fix it. Especially since in this case it is likely to be easy to find the problem and to fix it (just a guess).

Comment: @Drew not sure about that. I get the messages buffer open irrespective of whether there is a problem. With `emacs -Q` for example. This hack will just hide it.

Comment: If you get it with `emacs -Q` then that sounds like an Emacs bug to me. That does not happen to me with `emacs -Q`, using any Emacs version from Emacs 20 through the latest Emacs 25 dev snapshot. (But then again, I'm on MS Windows. But it also did not happen to me in the old days, when I was using Emacs on UNIX. And it also does not happen to me on GNU/Linux using Emacs 21.3 (FWIW).)

Comment: @Drew I'm on Linux and I have always had the messages buffer open. On many different machines, distributions and emacs versions. I very much doubt this is a bug.

Comment: If you file a bug report you will find out soon enough whether it is considered a bug. ;-)  I cannot imagine that this would intentionally be different on different platforms.

Comment: Doing this leaves me with two `*scratch*` panes.

Comment: @Dave strange, no idea why. By the way, I had assumed the OP didn't want the messages buffer _in general_. I had not understood that there was a syntax error in the init file causing it to appear in the foreground and not just loaded along with `*scratch*` in the background. That's why I said this always appears.